# Mysql query with ON DUPLICATE KEY Update, remove items not in values query

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
ID  adv_nr  day item1 item2 item3
1   2       2   10    23    34
2   2       3   11    23    34
3   2       4   10    24    34
4   2       5   10    35    34
5   3       10  56    34    12
```

The key is set on ID (Primairy) and adv_nr in combination with day (UNIQUE).

If there is a change in item1 or item2 I do a ON DUPLICATE KEY Update, but how to handle in case of removal of day 4? I want to remove the row or set it on NULL.
Is there a way in the query to remove (Or UPDATE to NULL) the values that have adv_nr = 2 and don’t exist in the values of the query?
So the query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table  (`adv_nr`,`day`,`item1`,`item2`,`item3`)
    VALUES (2,2,10,24,34), (2,3,11,28,34), (2,4,10,35,34) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    Item1 = VALUES(item1),
    Item2 = VALUES(item2),
    Item3 = VALUES(item3);
```

How to remove (or UPDATE to NULL) the row with ID 4?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to cramp everything in one statement. Just `delete * from yourTable where adv_nr = 2; insert into ...`.

First of all, I don't think it's possible what you're asking for. Second, when you don't do it all in one step, it's less error prone. Easier to maintain and so on...

Just don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't seem to match what you are asking. I think you are asking, "if values for day=4 are not submitted then null out the item values." Your example query includes values for day 4.

So assuming that you are asking to null out any rows that do not have a VALUES entry, no there is no good way to do that in a single query. You could potentially use a TRIGGER to execute some logic AFTER INSERT.